# Background being pushed down

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

HTML:

```
<section id= "main">
    <h1> Hello </h1>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#main {
  background-image: url("http://www.fullhdwpp.com/wp-content/uploads/Railroad-Tracks-in-the-Autumn-2_www.FullHDWpp.com_.jpg?66e13c");  
  min-height: 600px;
}
```

Problem: My `<h1>` is pushing the background down, or anything else I put inside the section for that matter or if I make the font bigger, it goes down. What I'd like to accomplish is the supposedly very simple task of putting an image as a background/header and just have it stay there without moving, but I can't, what is the simplest way to achieve that? Any help or explanation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that the `"h1"` is margining its parent element together. This is natively default, and you can disapply that action by setting the `"h1"`'s margin to `0`:

```
h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

And optionally, add padding:

```
h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<section id= "main">
    <h1> Hello </h1>
</section>

#main {
    background-image: url(image1.jpg) repeat-x 0px 50px; 
    background-position: 0px 50px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

h1{
    margin:0;
}
```